# OR in sparql query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

[This sparql query on wikidata](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23Distribution%20of%20names%20of%20human%20settlements%20ending%20in%20%22-ow%22%20or%20%22-itz%22%20in%20Germany%0A%23added%20before%202016-10%0A%20%23defaultView%3AMap%0ASELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fcoord%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%09%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ486972%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP17%20wd%3AQ183%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FitemLabel%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Fcoord%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3FitemLabel%29%20%3D%20%22de%22%29%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%09%20FILTER%20regex%20%28%3FitemLabel%2C%20%22%28ow%7Citz%29%24%22%29.%0A%7D) shows all places in Germany (Q183) with a name that ends in -ow or -itz.

I want to extend this to look for places in Germany and, say, Austria.

I tried modifying the 8th line to something like:

```
wdt:P17 (wd:Q183 || wd:Q40);
```

in order to look for places in Austria (Q40), but this is not a valid query.

What is a way to extend the query to include other countries?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Afaik there is no syntax as simple as that. You can, however, use [`UNION`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#alternatives) to the same effect like this:

```sql
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?coord
WHERE 
{
    ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q486972;
              rdfs:label ?itemLabel;
              wdt:P625 ?coord;
    {?item wdt:P17 wd:Q183} 
    UNION 
    {?item wdt:P17 wd:Q40}
    FILTER (lang(?itemLabel) = "de") . 
    FILTER regex (?itemLabel, "(ow|itz)$").
}
```

or as an alternative create a new variable containing both countries using [`VALUES`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data):

```sql
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?coord
WHERE 
{
  VALUES ?country { wd:Q40 wd:Q183 }
  ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q486972;
        wdt:P17 ?country; 
        rdfs:label ?itemLabel;
        wdt:P625 ?coord;
  FILTER (lang(?itemLabel) = "de") . 
  FILTER regex (?itemLabel, "(ow|itz)$").
}
```